# Localization parameter as a subdirectory in the url. How to take into account the redirection in html?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

The idea is to redirect http://thesite.com/fr/page1.htm to http://thesize/page1.htm?lang=fr

I could find around how to set .htaccess and redirection is working with this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^fr/([^/]+)$ /$1?lang=fr [L,QSA]
```

But the problem I can not find a solution is from the redirected page itself. The paths to folders seem to be relative to the subdirectory /fr as to html it looks like it is in the subdirectory fr. What would be a clean solution for this? a  in the  on each page?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Can you show an example of the undesired behaviour?

Comment: The html in the "root" has

<link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

The file style.css is supposed to exist in the same directory than the html invoking it. When the html is accessed through redirection the style.css is not loaded. I understand that from the point of view of the browser because apparently it is in a subdirectory (fr)

I see theseoptions:
- through a <base dir
- referncing these files (stylesheets, images) through absolute paths (loosing some flexibility)

Just wanted to know what do people use as an "optimal" solution or if there's something wrong in this.

Comment: ah, okay. I'd say an absolute path is the way to go in that case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say using an absolute path is the way to go in this case.

- Adding `<base>` leads to other problems, because it changes the relative root for the whole page
- Using relative paths is too tiresome if you have multiple possible levels of sub-directories.

Comment: Yes, there seems to be no other solutions. Anyway the absolute path way has also its inconveniences as for example moving the whole site to a subfolder messes it(for example for testing several versions). As everything is php I will think of a way to "absolutize" programmatically :-). Just wanted to be sure there's not a standard solution.
Thank you Pekka!